# Ballerina docker image with MySQL Driver - how to

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-composer

using ballerina v.1.0.1. on Mac.
On host I put MySQL driver to /Library/Ballerina/ballerina-1.0.1/distributions/jballerina-1.0.1/bre/lib , run ballerine code and I was eble to connecto to DB.

When I created docker image with **build** command and spin a docker in compose env it failed with

> ApplicationError message=error in sql connector configuration: Failed
>   to get driver instance for
>   jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/api_svc?serverTimezone=UTC:No suitable
>   driver at ballerinax.java_jdbc:createClient(jdbc_client.bal:87)
>   ballerinax.java_jdbc.Client:__init(client_endpoint.bal:27)

Question: How can I mount properly MySQL driver in docker image? I cannot find any reference in the documentation.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using @docker annotation to create the Dockerfile or you have your own Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to package the MySQL driver jar with the executable jar file of your Ballerina program. This way, you don't need to copy files to the docker container, because `ballerina build` command produces a self-contained executable jar with all the dependencies.

In order to do this, you need to create a Ballerina project and a module. [This guide](https://v1-0.ballerina.io/learn/how-to-structure-ballerina-code/) contains more information on Ballerina projects.

Then, copy and paste the following section to the `Ballerina.toml` in your project directory.

```
[platform]
target = "java8"

    [[platform.libraries]]
    path = "<path-to-the-mysql-driver-jar-file>"
    modules = ["<name-of-the-ballerina-module>"]
```

Comment: yes, this worked like a charm ... One question: is path need to be absolute or can be relative from .toml level? I put my driver on same level and it worked.

Comment: Path can be relative. Example: https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/blob/master/tests/jballerina-integration-test/src/test/resources/packaging/balopath/case3/TestProject1/Ballerina.toml#L11

Answer (score 0):

You can copy files in to your docker images using the @docker:CopyFiles annotation. Example:

```
@docker:Config {}
@docker:CopyFiles {
    files: [
        { sourceFile: "./conf/data.txt", target: "/home/ballerina/data/data.txt" }
    ]
}

@docker:Expose {}
listener http:Listener helloWorldEP = new(9090);
```

Check this sample: https://github.com/ballerinax/docker/tree/master/samples/sample5

To add it to the ballerina distribution in the docker image you can copy to this target:

```
@docker:CopyFiles {
    files: [
        { sourceFile: "./libs/mysql-driver.jar", target: "/ballerina/runtime/bre/lib/" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: hmm. problem is when I attach to running ballerina container in /home there is only ballerina folder in with my module <file>.jar. Im not coftable just blindly put diver in folder that not exist... I need to try and let you know